# Can I remove IfModule mod_php5.c from htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can I remove IfModule mod_php5.c from htaccess if I am using PHP 7.0?

It has the following lines:

```
php_value memory_limit 768M 
php_value max_execution_time 18000
############################################ 
## disable automatic session start 
## before autoload was initialized 
php_flag session.auto_start off 
############################################ 
## enable resulting html compression 
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
########################################### 
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload 
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

Comment: Depends on what it's masking.

Comment: It has below lines. 
  php_value memory_limit 768M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000

  ############################################
  ## disable automatic session start
  ## before autoload was initialized

  php_flag session.auto_start off

  ############################################
  ## enable resulting html compression

  php_flag zlib.output_compression on

  ###########################################
  ## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

  php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

Comment: Use the [edit] button. Further missing information: SAPI (mod_php or FCGI/FPM) of both PHP versions, loaded/avail modules (suhosin is not in PHP7 e.g.), and setting deviations to your concrete php.inis